# std::stoul not throwing std::out_of_range

Tags: c++, exception, g++, g++4.8

Consider following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cerrno>

int main() {
    unsigned long num = strtoul("0xFFFFFFFFFFFF11223344556677889900AABBCCDDEEFF", NULL, 16);
    std::cout << std::strerror(errno) << "\n";
    unsigned long num2 = std::stoul("0xFFFFFFFFFFFF11223344556677889900AABBCCDDEEFF");
    std::stoul("hello world");
    return 0;
}
```

This code is expected to print some "Out of range" from strerror and then to throw out_of_range exception [according to documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul). It should never reach the last stoul line.

In practice, it does not throw on the second stoul statement. I have tried GCC 4.8.5 and MinGW 8.2.0, both failed to throw the out_of_range exception and only delivered invalid_argument on the last stoul statement.

Is this a bug that should be reported or am I missing something and this is expected behaviour?

Comment: If you want `stoul` to deduce the base you need to use `std::stoul(..., nullptr, 0)`.

Comment: Don't forget to zero `errno` before the operation (it's written only on failure, not success - which can be useful if you want to check once for a whole block of operations).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Default base for [`std::stoul`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul) is 10.
`stoul` reads `0`, `x` is invalid so the rest of the string is ignored and numeric value `0` is returned.

Use similar syntax as in `strtoul`:

```
unsigned long num2 = std::stoul("0xFFFFFFFFFFFF11223344556677889900AABBCCDDEEFF", nullptr, 16);
```

Or with automatic deduction of numeric base:

```
unsigned long num2 = std::stoul("0xFFFFFFFFFFFF11223344556677889900AABBCCDDEEFF", nullptr, 0);
```

Both of the above versions will throw. [See it online!](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CKLBIBqWkHYcliAq)

Comment: Yep the key is that the function interprets an integer _in_ the string, not an integer that's necessarily the entire string. I think the OP should be using `pos` to detect this case, assuming the need is to catch the error (and not just work around it by changing the base so the error goes away)